# How do you disable a dropdown in Google Spreadsheet for selected cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have requirement that User will Select the Type. Depending on the Type, user can select its respective SubType.
Time taken will be fetched depending on the SubType, then total time will be calculated by "Time Taken for 1 Quantity" multiplied by quantity selected by user from drop down. User will have the option to select quantity 1 to 100 ( I did this by drop down option in  data validation). I am able to do till here.

But the  problem is  if the user selects  SubType: TypeA6-a or TypeA6-b or TypeA6-c or TypeA8-a or TypeA8-b or TypeA8-c, Quantity should be always 1.( shouldn’t have the drop down 1 to 100), rest should have drop down. Please help me on this problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yg-omfXy9Zr_UrM6Si7rLB8LfLcQLvJocTGMlffW_XQ/edit?usp=sharing

Regards,
Adarsh

Comment: Hi @Adarsh S. Welcome to SO. You should try and improve your question title to represent the question you're asking, not the situation you're in. Take a look at the tour and help menu top right. Something like "How do you disable a dropdown in Google Spreadsheet" might work.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I will use relevant title moving forward :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for a specific value using App-script, and setting a new Range for the combo box. You could try something similar to this approach:

```
var aSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var aCell = aSheet.getActiveCell();
var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

if (aColumn == 2 &&  ( aSheet.getName() == 'User 1' ||  aSheet.getName() == 'User 2' ) ) {
        var range = aSheet.getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 2);
    var categoryName = aCell.getValue();
        categoryName = categoryName.replace(/\s/g, '');
    var row = aCell.getRow();
    If (categoryName = "TypeA6-a") {
        aSheet.getRange(row, 4).setValue( 1 );
    }
  }
```